# Continuous function from a connected set?

Tags: continuity, connectedness

If $ f $ is a continuous mapping from a connected set to the real numbers and there exists a real number s that nothing maps to, then the image is either greater than or less than s.
this is clear to me intuitively but I can't think of how to prove it.

Comment: The image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected. Do you know what connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ look like?

Comment: yes; if x,y arereal numbers and x<z<y, then z is a real number

Comment: Okay, here's a better suggestion: the sets $\{m:f(m)>s\}$ and $\{m:f(m)<s\}$ are both open (why?), disjoint, and cover $M$. Therefore, one of them is...

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize those two sets were separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the set of points $m\in M$ for which $f(m) > s$ and let $V$ be the set of points $m\in M$ for which $f(m) < s$. Then $M = U \cup V$ and since $f$ is continuous, $U$ and $V$ is open. Since $U\cap V = \emptyset$, the set $\{U,V\}$ is a disconnection of $M$ unless $U = \emptyset$ or $V = \emptyset$. So since $M$ is connected, either $U = \emptyset$ or $V = \emptyset$.

Comment: got it,thanks kobe