# How to prove that a continuous mapping from a compact, connected space..

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, connectedness

If $ f $ is a continuous mapping from a compact, connected metric space M to the real numbers and there exists a real number s such that f(m) never equals s, then there exists a constant $ c>0 $ such that either $ f(m)>s+c $ or $ f(m)<s-c.$
Intuitively this makes sense but I can't come up with a proof.

Comment: This is related to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1129766/147263), asked from a different account. (If you are going to continue using this site, you should register your account: see the profile link on top of the screen). In addition to what was done there,  use the fact that a continuous function function attains extreme values on a compact set.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't figure out how to ask it with the same one

Comment: does the metric space necessarily have to be compact for this to be true?

Comment: Think of a continuous function on $(0,1)$ that does not attain its supremum and infimum.

Comment: You need compactness to be sure that the image is compact, and connectedness to be sure that the image is connected. You need both properties to conclude your result.